# How to access particular variable of object stored in node of singly linked list (iteration)

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

This is a very specific question, and I can't seem to find anything in particular which helps. I have a singly linked list( not an implemented linked list, which is all I've been able to find)in which the nodes store a Student object.Each Student object has variables, although I'm having trouble accessing each variable.

I think it's supposed to be similar to how you'd iterate through an array of objects.But that uses the for loop.And to traverse a linked list you have to work with the nodes and their next&data values.

I'm not entirely sure how to go about combining the 2 ideas.I feel like it's either something stupidly simple I'm not getting, or there's an entirely different approach I'm supposed to be taking.

```
import java.util.scanner;

public class StudentNode extends Student
{
private Student data;
private StudentNode next;


class SinglyLinkedList
{

 private StudentNode first;

 //constructor
 public SinglyLinkedList()
 {
     first=null;
 }


 public addToList(Student newData)
 {
     StudentNode newNode= new StudentNode();
     newNode.data=newData;
     newNode.next=first; //refs to the element first is currently pointing to
     first=newNode;//first now refs to added element
 }           

 public courseMark(Student data)
 {
     double cm=courseMark(StudentNode.data);
     return "Student number : "+stuNum +"Course Mark: "+cm;

 }



public double classAverage(Student data)
{
//traverses linked list, not enirely sure about how to access the course mark
    double classAvg=0;
    double sum = 0;
    int i=0;
    StudentNode current = first;
    StudentNode previous = null;
    while (current != null) 
    {
        i++;  
        StudentNode current= Student.courseMark();
        sum += current.data;//not sure bout course mark access
        previous = current;
        current = current.next;
     }
   return classAvg=sum/i;
  }
```

And here's the Student class which the data component uses. Not sure if it'll be needed to answer.

```
public class Student
{
private String name;
private String stuNum;
private int firstTest;
private int secondTest;
private int thirdTest;

public Student(String n,String sN,int fT,int sT,int tT)
{
    name=n;
    stuName=sN;
    firstTest=fT;
    secondTest=sT;
    thirsTest=tT;
}

//setters
public void setName(String n)
{
    name=n;
}    

public void setStuNum(String sN)
{
    stuNum=sN;
}

public void setFirstTest(int fT)
{
    firstTest=fT;
}

public void setSecondTest(int sT)
{
    secondTest=sT;
}

public void setThirdTest(int tT)
{
    thirdTest=tT;
}

//getters

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public String getStuNum()
{
    return stuNum;
}

public int getFirstTest()
{
    return firstTest;
}

public int getSecondTest()
{
    return secondTest;
}

public int getThirdTest()
{
    return thirdTest;
}

//course mark computer

public double courseMark()
{
    double crseMark=(firstTest*0.25)+(secondTest*0.25)+(thirdTest*0.50);
    return crseMark;
}
```

}

Comment: You are reinventing the `java.util.LinkedList<E>` class.  Are you required to write your own Linked List? If not, use the library class.  If writing a Linked List implementation is part of the course work then you need to study the textbook and lecture notes, as this will have been covered.  Have you studied `Iterable` and `Iterator`?  These are important concepts for working with lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must traverse from the node to the student data to get the courseMark.

`while (current != null) {
        ...
        double courseMark = current.data.courseMark();
        ...
    }`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was thinking about doing current.data.courseMark. But it looked weird, and I wasn't sure if it would be allowed.